# what will happen when two users submit same form and the php code having more than one queries will be executed on the server?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to ask that what will happen when two user will submit the same form and then the php code having more than one queries in more than one for loops and if statements which alter the table data will be executed?
I want to know that will all the queries in the php code will run for the first user first then for next one or will the query from both users will run simultaneously and if the queries will run simultaneously then what can i do stop that and execute all the queries of the first user first then of the second user?

Comment: [SQL Server Transaction Locking and Row Versioning Guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856598%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Comment: [Types of Concurrency Control](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189132%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: It has been 6 years since I asked this question and today I came across this again. I can clearly see where I was and where I am today. That time I was curious about all the stuff I was coming across and very very motivated to learn new things. Thanks to everyone who helped me then. Cool people like you are the reason why I am where I am today and Computer Science is where it is today. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL-Server doesn't know anything about your PHP code - it just perceives a series of queries and statements being sent to it. If your PHP function isn't atomic with regard to the database operations it performs you must explicitly handle these race conditions yourself, e.g., by locking the table or the relevant rows.

Note that depending on the isolation level you are using, changes to the tables' data performed by one session may or may not be visible to the other sessions. This isolation, however, by itself, is not sufficient to guarantee a function's atomicity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer brother :)